# How to virtually click a button in a userform using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform with 4 buttons.

I want to start the userform with button 1 already active.

The button is a public sub called "StartMeasButton_Click()" and is inside the userform. I need to click on that button.

I tried the Application.Run method but it fails, as I've understood, as the method is for a spreadsheet command button and not for a userform inside button.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution: Make your button click call a subroutine, then you can call the subroutine whenever you want to "click" the button.

```
 Sub StartMeasButton_Click()
     MySubRoutine
 End Sub

 Sub MySubRoutine()
   'put the body of your click routine here
 End Sub

 Sub Form1_Initialise
     MySubRoutine  'effectively the same as clicking the button
  End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use code to "click" or "press" a command button just set the value to true. This will fire the commandbutton's code events.

```
UserForm1.CommandButton1.Value = True
```

Comment: miken32 while your edit is polite. The issue remains. OP questions need to be addressed more directly. I honestly think it'd be better to just delete this answer.

Answer (score 0):

If it's allways the same "StartMeasButton" button, you can simply write a line like this:

```
StartMeasButton_Click
```

However, it can be dynamically generated if you use the "CallByName" method:

```
CallByName objForm, objButton.Name & "_Click", VbMethod
```